# Align the list in the footer to center

Tags: html, css

My site footer is having few links right now as shown below and it can be N number of links in the future. basically i want to align the links to center of the footer. i know it would work if i add fixed width or position to the following CSS i have written. but i don't want to set any fixed width as the number of links can increase in the future. What would be the best way to align the links to the center.

[image]

**HTML CODE**

```
  <footer>
      <ul>
          <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>          
      </ul>
   </footer>
```

**CSS**

```
  footer{
      background: #EEEEEE;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: 30px;
      padding-top: 20px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
  }
  footer ul{
  margin: 0px;
  }
  footer li {
      float: left;
      list-style-type: none;
      line-height: 9px;
      height: 11px;
      border-right: 1px solid #354052;
      padding: 0px 10px;
  }
  footer li a{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #354052;
      font-size: 12px;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```css
footer{
      background: #EEEEEE;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: 30px;
      padding-top: 20px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
  }
  footer ul{
  margin: 0px;
    padding:0;
  }
  footer li {
    /*  float: left;  */
      list-style-type: none;
      line-height: 9px;
      height: 11px;
      border-right: 1px solid #354052;
      padding: 0px 10px;
    display:inline;
  }
  footer li a{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #354052;
      font-size: 12px;
  }
```

```html
<footer>
      <ul>
          <li> <a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>          
      </ul>
   </footer>
```

Comment: comment footer li  /* float:left; */ add display:inline;

Answer (score 1):

Because you have `float:left` on all of your list items, this is always pushing them to the far left of the parent div, and will not be overridden by your text alignment CSS call.

So the simplist way to fix this would be to:

Get rid of the float on your list items and display them as inline blocks.

You probably don't need to, but I would also to be sure, change the margin on your list to try and centre the items.

https://jsfiddle.net/leecollingsco/emaqyxbv/

Note: I've had to monkey around with some of your other CSS to achieve the same styling as you show in your original screenshot, as the removal of floated items affects this.

Answer (score 0):

Just give `display: flex;` to `footer` and

```
footer ul {
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

will work for you.

**[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/thj53jtr/2/)**

Answer (score 0):

```
footer li {
    /* float: left; */
    display: inline-block;
}
```

I removed floating from your LI element, and made it inline-block. It should then respect text-align: center from the parent.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this code :

```
footer{
      background: #EEEEEE;
      margin: 0 auto;
      height: 30px;
      padding-top: 20px;
      width: 100%;
      text-align: center;
  }
  footer ul{
      margin: 0px;
      clear:both;
      text-align:center;
  }
  footer ul li {
      list-style-type: none;
      display:inline-block;       
      border-right: 1px solid #354052;
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 5px;
  }
  footer ul li a{
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #354052;
      font-size: 12px;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
footer ul {
    width:400px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

change the width according to your design and rest of your code is fine. good luck!

Please mark this answer if it was helpful.